# How can I specify string array as acceptable Routes for ASP.NET Web API controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET Web API controller, and my application is database driven application and is set up in such a way that I can possibly have about 50-60 routes that can use the same controller.

It looks like this:

```
[Route(EndpointConstants.EndpointABC)]
[Route(EndpointConstants.EndpointXYZ)]
..
..//There can be 50-60 routes that can go here
..
public class ReportController : ControllerBase
{
   [HttpPost]
   [Produces(MediaTypeConstants.Json)]
   [Route("")]
   public async Task<ActionResult<ApiResponse>> Process(ClassName objectName)
   {
       return await ...
   }
}
```

In this case this can get very top-heavy class and I have to hardcode all the possible routes with `Route` attribute. And I have a bunch of controllers like this in my app which can have their own specific list of routes.

So my question is - Is there a way I can possibly use `string[]` as `Routes` for this controller? Something like below -

```
var EndpointConstantsList = new [] {
   "ABC",
   "XYZ",
   "DEF"
};

[Routes(EndpointConstantsList)]
public class ReportController : ControllerBase
{
   [HttpPost]
   [Produces(MediaTypeConstants.Json)]
   [Route("")]
   public async Task<ActionResult<ApiResponse>> Process(ClassName objectName)
   {
       return await ...
   }
}
```

Comment: No. In .NET, attribute parameters have to be `const` values (though not necessarily literals), including `const String`.

Comment: _"my application is database driven application and is set up in such a way that I can possibly have about 50-60 routes that can use the same controller."_ - that makes no sense to me - it sounds like you should address your routing-design problem first. What exactly are all these routes? Why can't you use a _single_ parameterized route template to match all of them?

Comment: I don't understand the reasons either, but the solution might be to use a [T4 template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-and-t4-text-templates) or a [Source Generator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/source-generators-overview).

Comment: You can catch all routes; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#route-templates `[Route("{**slug}")]`?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman - Route teamplates didnt work for me since I also have a requirement for validating endpoints based on different parameters. IRouteConstraint option worked best for me as mentioned in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind add a section and add a key-value pair in your routedata dictionary

A possible solution for you:

```
public class MyConstraint : IRouteConstraint
    {
        private static readonly string[] AllowedValues = new string[] { "ABC", "XYZ" };

        public bool Match(
            HttpContext? httpContext, IRouter? route, string routeKey,
            RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
        {
            if (!values.TryGetValue(routeKey, out var routeValue))
            {
                return false;
            }

            var routeValueString = Convert.ToString(routeValue, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            if (routeValueString is null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return AllowedValues.Contains(routeValueString, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        }
    }
```

Regist it:

```
builder.Services.AddRouting(options =>
    options.ConstraintMap.Add("myconstraint", typeof(MyConstraint)));
```

Apply it to controller:

```
[Route("{newsection:myconstraint}")]
```

Result:
[image]